# Small text and safe CMYK values to ensure as crisp text as possible

Tags: adobe-indesign, cmyk, halftone

I am working in an InDesign magazine where I need to have a fair amount of small text (10pt) in many different colors; thus impossible to use *only one* additional spot color.

My concern is that if I use CMYK values that are *random* numbers like 72,3% in any of CMYK value, halftoning will appear and make the small text not crisp.

Do I worry too much? I don't expect the result to be 100% same as printing black in 0/0/0/100 but something close to that.

If my concern is valid, are there any practical rules to follow?

Comment: This is just a tough assignment for multiple reasons: likely registration problems (very likely), diminished readability because of poor contrast, and halftoning, as you mentioned. If you can't use 100% ink and no more than two plates, I would be absolutely sure to get press checks before going ahead.

Comment: My answer [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/85705/84899) is somewhat related.

Comment: 10pt is not really small text. It’s perfectly normal for books to be set in 10pt text, for example, and if you’re having your document offset-printed, most colours will be perfectly legible.

Answer (score 2):

The first obvious options.

Cian 100% and Magenta 100%

From there you have different values that can potentially look your text screened and out of register.

**First the screening**. I would use either cyan or magenta at 100% and some other color with a smaller percentage. Oranges, greens, turquoise.

A 50% color is a checkerboard pattern, lower values dominate the white or the no-color, so probably try to stay above, let's say 60% so it is more color with white dots inside.

If it is yellow it does not really matter.

Here is an image which is not the exact same case as using a smaller than 100% ink. The problem here is a text converted to bitmap. but it is a similar issue.

You can see the proportion between the screening and the font size.

[image]

Try to use bold fonts, not light versions.

---

You can still **registry issues**.

In this case try to use just one ink, like cyan at 60%.

Avoid printing on large machines or large paper, where there can potentially be more deformation on the rubber (For example A0 or A1). Try to print on a smaller one like A2.

But this totally depends on the quality of the press, costs, number of copies, type of paper, etc.

Talk to the printer about the specific issue.